# Can I set default language of download data from Google API Geocode?

Tags: android, json, api, google-maps

This is my method which is used to parse `JSONObject` to strings.

```
private Map<String, String> parseJSONObject (JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
    Map<String, String> city = new HashMap<>();

    JSONArray Results = json.getJSONArray("results");
    JSONObject zero = Results.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray address_components = zero.getJSONArray("address_components");

    for (int i = 0; i < address_components.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject zero2 = address_components.getJSONObject(i);
        String long_name = zero2.getString("long_name");
        JSONArray mtypes = zero2.getJSONArray("types");
        String Type = mtypes.getString(0);

        city.put(Type, long_name);
    }

    return city;
}
```

To get data from API I use that URL: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=CITY_NAME&sensor=true`.

And my question is: How can I set default language of data which is downloaded by me? For example, as `administrative_area_level_1` I get `Masovian Voivodeship` instead of `Mazowieckie` which is what I need (name of voivodeship in polish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can find in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), there's an optional parameter for setting the result language.

> language — The language in which to return results. See the list of supported domain languages. Note that we often update supported languages so this list may not be exhaustive. If language is not supplied, the geocoder will attempt to use the preferred language as specified in the Accept-Language header, or the native language of the domain from which the request is sent. The geocoder will do its best to provide a street address that is readable for both the user and locals. To achieve that goal, it will return street addresses in the local language, transliterated to a script readable by the user if necessary, observing the preferred language. All other addresses will be returned in the preferred language. Address components will all be returned in the same language, which is chosen from the first component. Should names not be available in the preferred language, the closest match will be used.

You can find the list of supported languages [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport).

So in your case for Polish your API url is going to be something like:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=CITY_NAME&sensor=true&language=pl
```

Comment: You are welcome :D don't forget to mark the answer as the solution if it helped you ;)